# Debugging with node-inspector code deployed by Grunt, non-Grunt module

Tags: express, gruntjs, node-inspector

I am deploying my Express Server using Grunt and grunt-express plugin. I am trying to attach the node-inspector debugger to the code running on my server with:

node --debug ($which grunt) my_task

In my Chrome debugging window (I use Chrome) I can see many JS files loaded under "Scripts" tab, but all of them are the code from Grunt and Gruntacular modules and Gruntfile.js

So I can't put a breakpoint in my own Express code.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

I personally just had the same issue. Except I was running node-inspector directly on my app.js/server.js file that contains all of my express config and routing.

If you click in the file pane and start typing it will show you were a certain file is. I could not access my app.js file directly, but i could access all of the requires.

So, in my case --

- clicking in file pane
- typing `routes.js` jumped straight to routes.js
- double click to open file
- click a number line to set break point
- run your app and wait for it to pause.

  - if you dont see anything happening try reloading the browser and using the app again
  - if that doesnt work try restarting the app server, and restarting node-inspector using

  `sudo node --debug app.js`
  `sudo node-inspector`